# OneDrive and Recycle bin

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, recycle-bin

I am a bit confused on how OneDrive and deleted items work.

I've my desktop synched, and when I delete an item it goes to my Windows 10 Recycle bin (and also OneDrive Recycle bin).

If I log on to another PC, Would the recycle bin sync?

How about creating an item from OneDrive web portal and deleting it? Sometimes I see it in my desktop recycle bin and sometimes not.

Can anybody explain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OneDrive is Cloud Storage, you can imagine it as a computer in the sky.

When you sync OneDrive with Windows, it creates a parallel bridge between the two and any changes made to one side is made to the other. So if you create a work document in the OneDrive folder on windows, it will sync into the cloud.

Now deleted items are a little different, when you delete something on onedrive.com, it will go to the recycle bin (on onedrive.com) which is the Cloud Storage - that will sync accross all devices)

However, if you delete something on windows, it will only go to the recycle bin ON that computer and will not sync across.